# Swift Buttonaction Text Change

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to make the text change when its pressed and shows different type of map (Hybrid, standard or satellite).
But when i press the button i get error (well, not when i don't have the "textchange" code in it). So how do i make the text change when it knows its different type of map without getting this error and crashing the app...?

i use this code

```
   @IBAction func mapType(sender: AnyObject) {
    if Mapview.mapType == MKMapType.Standard {
        Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
        sender.setTitle("Satellite", forState: .Normal)

    } else {
        if Mapview.mapType == MKMapType.Satellite {
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
            sender.setTitle("Hybrid", forState: .Normal)

    } else {
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
            sender.setTitle("Standard", forState: .Normal)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use `UISegmentedControl` when switching between three states.

Create an `IBAction` with CTRL dragged connection from your Storyboard's UISegmentedControl element.

Implement the method as following:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)        
    // if states within your control is indexed in following order: Standard, Satellite, Hybrid:

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        case 1:
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
        case 2:
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
        default:
            Mapview.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    }            
}
```

Comment: Made a label and made it change text instead. Thanks though